# Side identification on a hexagon

Tags: general-topology, geometry, geometric-topology

Apparently giving a hexagon side identification aabbcc results in a sphere. I'm struggling to see this, can someone explain? perhaps with a diagram? It seems to be all the vertices are identified, but I have been told this is not the case.

[image]

Comment: Do you know what a net of a polyhedron is ?... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(polyhedron)

Comment: I thought I did. Is it helpful here?

Comment: Seems to me that what results is not actually a sphere. Wrong fundamental group, wrong homology.

Comment: what is the euler characteristic here?

Comment: It would be better to add a picture to explain how the identification is made. Even with a square, by identifying opposite sides we can get a torus, a Klein bottle or a projective plane.

Comment: I've added a picture, can anyone identify this surface?

Comment: This surface has Euler characteristic -1, in particular your surface won't be orientable. I don't know any name for this surface

Comment: That's what I thought! must be a typo in a problem i'm attempting

Comment: I think you need to consider the surface $aa^{-1}bb^{-1}cc^{-1}$. If I am not mistaken, it will give you a sphere

Comment: the problem i am doing wanted me to prove the euler characteristic is always nonnegative when we start with a hexagon, so this is a counterexample i think :)

Comment: In the language of the classification theorem for surfaces, this surface is a connected sum of three projective planes, which makes it the "surface with nonorientable genus 3". Because it has the smallest possible negative Euler characteristic $-1$, that means it is the closed hyperbolic surface of smallest area.